# Show that two matrices A and B are row equivalent iff there exists an invertible matrix C so that A=CB

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Show that two matrices $A,B\in \text{Mat}_{m,n}(\mathbb{F}$) are row equivalent iff there exists an invertible matrix $C\in \text{Mat}_{n}(\mathbb{F}$), so that $A=C\cdot B$.

Is the solution that $C$ is row equivalent with the identity matrix since $C$ is invertible? I'm still trying to grasp the basics :-)

Comment: The first step is (probably) to write down what it means for two matrices to be row equivalent

Comment: I'm not sure that I'm thinking this right :/

Comment: Hint: prove that every row operation can be achieved by multiplying the matrix by an invertible matrix from the left. And then notice that doing various operations can be achieved by multiplying from the left various times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any invertible matrix can be written as a composition of elementary matrices (each of which represents an elementary row operation). Now, apply the definition of row equivalence. This proves the statement.